# Find non-centrality parameter in effect size CI estimation

Tags: r

I'm trying to find confidence intervals around effect sizes. To do so, I need to find the non-centrality parameter associated with *t* distributions with 0.025 and 0.975 probability relative to the corresponding *t* statistic (see [here](https://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/methods7/Supplements/Confidence%20Intervals%20on%20Effect%20Size.pdf) for more detail).

My question is what's the most efficient way to go about finding the correct non-centrality parameters? My solution at present is a brute force approach (which is actually sort of recommended by the author). For example

```
# test data
d <- c(1.73, 1.06, 2.03, 1.40, 0.95, 1.13, 1.41, 1.73, 1.63, 1.56)

# t-test of difference from 1
t_test <- t.test(d, rep(1, length(d)))

# calculate probability of the t stat with many ncps
prob <- mapply(pt, t_test$statistic, t_test$parameter, seq(-15, 15, length = 1e4))

probs <- data.frame(ncp = seq(-15, 15, length = 1e4), prob = prob)

probs$upper <- 0.025 - probs[ ,2]
probs$lower <- 0.975 - probs[ ,2]

# find ncp for upper bound
probs[which.min(abs(probs$upper)), 1]
## [1] 7.007201

# find ncp for lower bound
probs[which.min(abs(probs$lower)), 1]

## [1] 1.471647
```

These are correct, but it seems like there should be more efficient methods. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share with us what you ended up doing to find non-centrality parameters? I'm also trying to find the optimal way to put a CI around Cohen's d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like statistical gibberish to me, much like the useless task of doing post-hoc power analyses. But I thought one could easily set these two calculations up as optim calls, albeit, with minimal utility for this exercise:

```
> optim( par =c( x=1), 
         function( ncp) abs(0.025-pt(t_test$statistic, t_test$parameter, ncp) ))
$par
       x 
7.007642 

$value
[1] 2.925137e-08

$counts
function gradient 
      56       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

Warning message:
In optim(par = c(x = 1), 
         function(ncp) abs(0.025 - pt(t_test$statistic,  :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly

> optim( par =c( x=1), 
         function( ncp) abs(0.975-pt(t_test$statistic, t_test$parameter, ncp) ))
$par
       x 
1.472336 

$value
[1] 1.113777e-10

$counts
function gradient 
      56       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Not sure I agree it's "statistical gibberish" but I'd be interested in hearing your thoughts. I have actually never seen the approach criticized, and it is fairly widely used. For example, see Cumming and Finch (2001) (http://epm.sagepub.com/content/61/4/532.abstract) and also Kelley (2007) (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.218.7510&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: The first citation is to a pay-only site. The second discusses CI's for effect sizes but what I calculated above were not effect sizes. Effect sizes are ratios of t-statistics to standard deviations. What is above is an estimate of something for which I see no purpose.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I probably did not do a good job of explaining my purpose, which is to calculate CI's for effect sizes. The calculation of the non-central *t* is an intermediary step, where the values found are divided by the square root of the *df* to get the lower and upper bounds. So in the example I provided, the ES = (mean(d) - 1) /sd(d) = 1.36, with a lower bound of 1.472336/sqrt(9) = 0.491 and an upper bound of 7.007642/sqrt(9) = 2.34. The example I provided is directly from the linked citation in the question, if you'd like to investigate further. Again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: While it is true that non-central t distributions are skewed, in practice they are really only importantly so when the degrees of freedom are less than 6. I did (unpublished) work 20 years ago coming up with confidence intervals for risk ratios using non-central t's and abandoned it after I could find no practical impact. I decided it was a case of "guilding the lily".

Comment: Interesting... and that really makes a lot of sense. Perhaps I'll investigate this some on my own.

Comment: Apologies for misspelling `gilding`.